# how can enable the zoom in uiwebview using swift without using the scalesPageToFit=true property because it cause Sequese webview

Tags: swift, uiwebview, ios10, swift4

I want to enable the zoom in zoom out functionality on `UIWebView` using swift. I've applied the following and all help available on stack over flow and others. I dont want to use the `scalesPageToFit` functionality provided by apple when I use `scalesPageToFit = true` the zoom in zoom out functionality start working other wise it will disabled and I dont want to set my webview property as `scalesPageToFit= true` because when I use `scalesPageToFit= true` my web view Sequese.

> when i set scalesPageToFit= true [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fIgY.jpg
>
> when the scalesPageToFit=false but it will not zoom in zoom out the web view when i set this property as false [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUU9B.jpg
> use the following code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.web_Description.delegate = self
    self.web_Description.scrollView.delegate = self
    self.web_Description.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    self.web_Description.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    self.web_Description.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    self.web_Description.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0
    self.web_Descriptio.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]').setAttribute('content', 'user-scalable = 1;', false); ")
}

func scrollViewDidEndZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView,with view: UIView?,atScale scale: CGFloat) {
    self.web_Descriptio.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]').setAttribute('content', 'user-scalable = 1;', false); ")
}
```